# Should we make [mysql-backup] tag a synonym of [mysql]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[mysql-backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-backup) has no guidance and is quite vague in my opinion. It only has 110 question at the time of writing this post. If the only purpose is to denote an action on MySQL DB this tag is not very helpful. Recently [mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqldump) was made a synonym of [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and I think this one should follow.

There also other new sub-MySQL tags popping up e.g. [mysqlpump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqlpump), which in my opinion do not help, but add to the confusion. It is easy to make the typo between `mysqldump` and `mysqlpump` when tagging the question.

Is it a good idea to make sub-tags for MySQL tools?

Comment: Why would we replace a specific and properly applied tag that actually describes the content of the question with an overly general tag that doesn't describe the content of the question very well at all? Tags don't take up space, and we do not have an inherent need to slim down on our tag database. We only remove or retire tags if they are actively causing harm.

Comment: @TinyGiant It is a fair point, however I do not agree with you 100%. We are creating niche tags which make it more difficult to find such questions and answer them [ex.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41613253/1839439) [ex.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44608398/1839439) [ex.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45750105/1839439) [ex.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26267146/1839439)

Comment: Additionally there is a very similar tag called [tag:mysqlbackup.net] which can be easily confused with this one.

Answer (score 0):

What is vague about mysql-backup? It is about a process  often used by developers so questions about it in a developer context are on-topic.

All the database systems out there are vast in their supporting tools and processes. Putting them all under one tag makes it harder for those that want to answer questions related to those tools to subscribe to question in that tag.

Not allowing a tag to exist because there is one letter difference is not a very convincing argument. You should start with the creators of mysqlpump and blame them for their awful naming scheme.

Tools and processes used by developers in a development context are on-topic and deserve their own tag so you can either find those questions to answer them or put them on your ignore list because you hate those tools.

Comment: [mysql-backup] is not a tool here. It is being used for a statement that dumps all the data in a .sql file. Or any other means to back up.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

Comment: It is vague, because it describes an action rather than a piece of technology or a tool. The tool for mysql backup is [tag:mysqldump] which is now a synonym of MySQL. Personally I would prefer [tag:mysqldump] over [tag:mysql-backup]. If we go by action then we would also need `mysql-insert`, `mysql-select` and so on...

Comment: It doesn't matter what can happen in the future or which legit tags you envision to be possible. There is a tag, it is used. I see not much going wrong with questions in that tag. I don't think that tag should be synonym of the bulk on [tag:mysql].